# Cant set correct .Net version in IIS Server Pool

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016

I am trying to setup a .Net based RestApi that should be hosted on a Windows Server running IIS. But for some reason i have no luck getting my pool configured as needit to make it work.

Here is the vendors description of how to go about it. [WindWard Docs](https://ohana.windwardstudios.com/m/89237/l/1082342-getting-started-with-net-restful-engine)

It states the following

> Click on the "Select…" button next to the "Application pool" text
> field. Click on the drop down list and select one of the options:
>
> ASP.NET v4.0 .NET 4.5 or .NET 4.0 (Although you may only see .NET 4.0
> or .NET 4.5, if you have .NET 4.5.1 installed, either option will
> work.)
> And i should see this option
> [image]

But no matter what version i install 2012R2, 2016 or 2019 i never see that, i always get the below option, so not sure what i am missing here

[image]

Comment: That's due to the example shown was from over 10 years ago. What you see now is correct, you only have one option and that is .NET CLR 4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There really have been (*) only two .NET releases: 2.0 and 4.0.

3.0 and 3.5 are just additions to 2.0.

4.5, 4.7, 4.8 are just additions to 4.0.

And yes, the IIS UI is even more confusing.

Anyway, 4.x just means "anything going forward from 4.0". Just select any 4.x runtime and you should be fine.

---

(*) It got *even worse* later.

Answer (score 1):

When Microsoft initially designed IIS 7, they thought that the CLR versions would stick to .NET Framework versions, so that an application pool can have 1.0, 1.1, or 2.0 version of .NET Framework.

However, the introduction of .NET Framework 3.0/3.5 broke the rule, as they were still on CLR 2.0. Similarly, all .NET Framework 4.x releases use CLR 4.0. So the legacy UI you saw from that WindWard article was unfortunately confusing. You can find a lot of Stack Overflow/ServerFault threads with similar background.

What you now observe in IIS Manager is the latest UI (not easy to recall when it was first introduced, maybe IIS 10) where Microsoft lists CLR versions explicitly. It can still be hard to beginners to understand, as not all .NET developers fully know the CLR concepts in detail, but at least less confusing.